# InnoDB: Ignoring data file './catalog_category_product_index_store1.ibd' with space ID 26146, since the redo log references

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb, innodb

I m running Magento 2.3.3 on VPS.

how to fix this? my InnoDB is not working on mariadb server getting this is error log.

```
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1.ibd' with space ID 26146, since the redo log references ./my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1.ibd with space ID 26031.
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1.ibd' with space ID 26141. Another data file called ./my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot rename './my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica.ibd' to './my_store/catalog_category_product_index_store1.ibd' for space ID 26141 because the target file exists. Remove the target file and try again.
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [ERROR] InnoDB:  Cannot replay file rename. Remove either file and try again.
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-01-22 19:24:28 140112818333888 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```